# How to create boolean column (WPF DevExpress Grid)

Tags: wpf, grid

does anyone knows how to create a boolean column for WPF DevExpress Grid.
A similar text column is generated like:

```
DevExpress.Wpf.Grid.GridColumn col = new GridColumn();
```

But how to create a boolean column, so that the check box would be appear on that column..?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the fieldname of that column to a boolean member of your data object it automatically present a checkbox

so say you have

```
class MyObj
{
   public bool MyProperty {get;set;}
   public string OtherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

you then do:

```
DevExpress.Wpf.Grid.GridColumn col = new GridColumn();
col.FieldName = "MyProperty";
```